# Looping objects :object is not valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem looping on object. I couldn't solve it. Please help me.
I am on a React project to improve my skill and gonna work with React Hooks.
There is a file like below which contains an object. I'm gonna fetch from an api. I wanna to display the object details which i need on the page.
I've tried a lot of way to solve but they didn't work.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function ValueRef() {

    const myList = {
        "location_suggestions": [
          {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "London",
            "country_id": 215,
            "country_name": "United Kingdom",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_215.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 142,
            "state_name": "England and Wales",
            "state_code": "England and Wales"
          },
          {
            "id": 3454,
            "name": "London, ON",
            "country_id": 37,
            "country_name": "Canada",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_37.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 124,
            "state_name": "Ontario",
            "state_code": "ON"
          },
          {
            "id": 5836,
            "name": "London, KY",
    
import React from 'react';

export default function ValueRef() {

    const myList = {
        "location_suggestions": [
          {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "London",
            "country_id": 215,
            "country_name": "United Kingdom",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_215.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 142,
            "state_name": "England and Wales",
            "state_code": "England and Wales"
          },
          {
            "id": 3454,
            "name": "London, ON",
            "country_id": 37,
            "country_name": "Canada",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_37.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 124,
            "state_name": "Ontario",
            "state_code": "ON"
          },
          {
            "id": 5836,
            "name": "London, KY",
```

Error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,
> name, country_id, country_name, country_flag_url,
> should_experiment_with, has_go_out_tab, discovery_enabled,
> has_new_ad_format, is_state, state_id, state_name, state_code}). If
> you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oversimplifying your object, it is something like this :

```
const myList = {
        "location_suggestions": [ ...objects ],
        "status": "success",
        "has_more": 0,
        "has_total": 0,
        "user_has_addresses": true
      }
```

Now, when you do :

```
Object.values(myList).map((detail)=>(<div>{detail}</div>))
```